# How to Draw Custom Shape Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I'm trying to create an arrow with rounded corners, but I'm not getting the result I want

```
private let arrowLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.2, y: 0.5)
    layer.lineWidth = 4
    layer.strokeColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    layer.lineCap = .round
    layer.lineJoin = .round

    return layer
}()
```

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    arrowLayer.bounds.size = CGSize(width: bounds.width * 0.27, height: bounds.width * 0.02)
    arrowLayer.position = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: arrowLayer.bounds.width, y: arrowLayer.bounds.height * 0.3))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: arrowLayer.bounds.width, y: arrowLayer.bounds.height * 0.7))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: arrowLayer.bounds.height))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
    path.close()

    arrowLayer.path = path.cgPath
}
```

**This is the result I get**

[image]

**I want to get this result**

[image]

I tried but didn't get the desired result

```
layer.lineCap = .round
layer.lineJoin = .round
```

Comment: line caps only work for the ends of lines, not for closed paths. Line joins only round the corners between line segments. If you want rounded ends on an irregular shape like the one you are drawing you'll have to add arcs on the ends as in @MojtabaHosseini s excellent answer

Comment: Your code as posted draws a horizontal line that is thicker on the left side. The sample images in your question show diagonal lines. What is the source of that difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to draw arcs on both sides like:

```
let minR: CGFloat = 10
let bigR: CGFloat = 20
var path = UIBezierPath()

path.move(to: .init(x: rect.midX - minR, y: minR))
path.addArc(
    withCenter: .init(x: rect.midX, y: minR),
    radius: minR,
    startAngle: .degrees(0),
    endAngle: .degrees(180),
    clockwise: true
)
path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.midX - bigR, y: rect.maxY - bigR))
path.addArc(
    withCenter: .init(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY - bigR),
    radius: bigR,
    startAngle: .degrees(0),
    endAngle: .degrees(180),
    clockwise: false
)
path.move(to: .init(x: rect.midX + bigR, y: rect.maxY - bigR))
path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.midX + minR, y: minR))
path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.midX - minR, y: minR))
path.addLine(to: .init(x: rect.midX - bigR, y: rect.maxY - bigR))
```

[image: Demo]

Don't forget to convert radians to degrees:

```
extension CGFloat {
    static func degrees(_ degrees: Double) -> Double { degrees * .pi / 180 }
}
```